# How to transpose col1, col2 in a table into row1 and row2? col1 is the parent of col2

Tags: sql

I have a table structure like below

```
seqno col1 col2 
1 Actuals apr19 
1 Actuals may19 
1 Actuals jun19 
2 budget apr19 
2 budget may19 
2 budget jun19
```

---

I need this in below format

```
     actuals                budget
apr19 may19 jun19       apr19 may19 jun19
```

Comment: The syntax is likely to be specific to the RDBMS you're using. Please tag your question with the actual database type and version.

Comment: do you want col2 be on date order or string order?

Comment: You will (very likely) need an aggregate function to build the columns based on a `GROUP BY` condition. The thing is, aggregate functions are very specific to the DB you are using, so we need a response to @EricBrandt's comment.

Comment: we are using sql server 2016

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a pivot operation. Every `RDBMS` has slightly different syntax for this operation. Here is one in Oracle:

> ```
> with t0 as (
>  select 'Actuals' as c1, 'apr19' as c2 from dual
>  union all select 'Actuals' as c1, 'may19' as c2 from dual
>  union all select 'Actuals' as c1, 'jun19' as c2 from dual
>  union all select 'budget' as c1, 'apr19' as c2 from dual
>  union all select 'budget' as c1, 'may19' as c2 from dual
>  union all select 'budget' as c1, 'jun19' as c2 from dual
> )
> select * 
> from (
>   select c1, c2
>   from t0 
> )
> pivot (max(c2) 
>        for c2 in ('apr19', 'may19', 'jun19'))
> ```
>
> ```
> C1      | 'apr19' | 'may19' | 'jun19'
> :------ | :------ | :------ | :------
> Actuals | apr19   | may19   | jun19  
> budget  | apr19   | may19   | jun19
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5c421fe265cea2be49d1f22d84319117)*